# How to call remote SOAP web service from an application using Apache Camel‏

Tags: apache, apache-camel

I have an Apache CXF SOAP service deployed on a web container Tomcat.

The web service is is published on TOMCAT on URL:

> [tomcat localhost url]/exemplar/Quote?wsdl

This wsdl has several web service operations exposed.
I want to call web service method `findQuote(int quoteId)` from an external application using Apache Camel.

Please guide me how to invoke a SOAP web service by passing request parameters and how to get the response in Apache Camel.

If anybody have a piece of code for this use case, then it would be of really very great help for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html for details about how to consume from an existing SOAP endpoint using the CXF destination. There are different **dataFormat** types that can be used to deliver the message body.